# Does cutting sweet potatoes with non stainless steel knives cause oxidation poisoning?

Tags: potatoes

I have found when cutting up sweet potatoes prior to cooking that the cut edges go grey or black when soaked in warm water. I read on another site that using a carbon or non stainless steel knife causes oxidization. So my question is, if this be true, is it a health hazard?

Comment: What kind of substances do you expect?

Comment: Hmm, must be time to get into the platinum knife selling business...Perhaps I can sell platinum pans, too.

Comment: Yeah, sweet potatoes where only widely discovered as edible after the stainless steel knife was invented, though there were a few pioneer cooks using brass, bronze or nickel knives. ;) (SARCASM)

Answer (score 3):

Oxidation is not a health hazard, no matter how you spell it. Your sweet potatoes are as healthy kind of brown as they ever were.